# Build a chain out of integer pairs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, integer

I have a set of integers pairs:

```
[4, 3], [0, 1], [0, 4], [2, 3], [2, 1]
```

The task is to chain it to get the output:

```
[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 0]
```

Are there any existed optimised algorithms to do it?

Comment: I think you can just sort them by first number in pair

Answer (score 3):

Make a graph where numbers are vertices and pairs are edges.

Check whether [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) exists (all vertex degrees are even (perhaps except for two vertices))

If yes, build this path